# SQL Server - I need code that will cause a stack dump

Tags: sql-server, stack-dump

I'm trying to create a repro script for a MS connect item, and need to be able to cause a stack dump at will.

How could I do that?

Comment: You picked a random ms connect item and now you need a script that reproduces the stack dump the ms connect item asks for? Strange question....

Comment: I assume he wants to add info to an existing item or open a new one

Comment: Correct, @Remus. I'm writing a connect item; if you set up an Event Notification on Server for ERRORLOG, you don't get all items.  Nothing with Source = "Server", and Stack Dumps don't appear to get caught either. I need a repro for the connect item. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`DBCC DUMPTRIGGER`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2008/01/10/how-it-works-sql-server-engine-error-messages.aspx) can be used to trigger a dump on a specific error.

You can also take a dump of at will, see [How to use the Sqldumper.exe utility to generate a dump file in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/917825) but those are less useful.

Comment: Just a note: in general is better to contact CSS for such issues. If they need a dump, they know how to take one.

Comment: In actually trying to force a dump because I've noticed that Event Notifications' ERRORLOG Trace Event doesn't capture them, and I want a repro script for a Connect item. Thanks, sir, I think that's what I need!